# Multiple Files from Google Client library - Drive API's Not Found

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I've installed Google.Api.Drives.v2 from Nuget without issue, but when I attempt to create the DriveService object, I get multiple file not found errors.  I used to get this occasionally when I ran Windows 8.1, VS2013, but with different Google Drive objects, and it was never so show stopping.  Since upgrading to VS2015, I am unable to get it to work, I've even completely removed all references to the Google Api's and reinstalled the packages and reset the references.  Here's the C# code I'm running:

```
            ClientSecrets GoogleSecrets = new ClientSecrets();
            GoogleSecrets.ClientId = ClientID;
            GoogleSecrets.ClientSecret = ClientSecret;
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleSecrets,

                new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore("Test")).Result;
```

And here's a picture of what I get when I debug:

[image]

If I continue to step through, I get this error for a ton of other files.  Some examples:  GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.cs, GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.cs, etc.

Eventually if I keep stepping through I get a System.AggregateException:  An unhandled exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

I'm sure it's something silly and simple.  Any advice would be most helpful, thank you!

Comment: Would you try and import this package instead please.   Install-Package Google.Apis.Drive.v2 -Version 1.9.2.1790   (I want to test something)

Comment: Thanks for responding!  So I cleaned out all the Google Api's (PM already believed it was installed) and then restarted my project, and reloaded.  I made sure I added it to to both projects in my solution and that all references were there in the list.  VS reports no errors or warnings either.  Google.Apis.Auth, Google.Apis.Drive.v2, and Google.Apis.Core all report there are newer version available, but I haven't applied those updates.  Unfortunately, with all of that - I still get the same result unfortunately.

Comment: log an issue.  I am going to have to install VS2015 to test this myself.  https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues

Comment: Ok, will do.  I'll try a few more things, and update as I gather more information.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. Follow these steps:

1. In visual studio go to `Tools` > `Import and export settings`
2. Select `Reset all settings` and click `Next`.
3. Done

---

[image]